# Will the EFT-1 mission for Orion carry an escape tower?

Tags: sls, orion-spacecraft, launch-escape-system, delta-iv-heavy, tractor-les

December 2014 is the scheduled date for the Exploration Flight Test-1 (EFT-1) mission of the Orion space capsule. It will be launched on a Delta IV Heavy rocket as a surrogate for the unavailable SLS booster.

Will it carry a Launch Escape System/Launch Abort System (LES/LAS) on this mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [NASASpaceflight.com](http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2013/12/heat-shield-eft-1-orion-ksc/) article from December 4, 2013, yes:

> Another element that will heading uphill on EFT-1 will be an inert
>   Launch Abort System (LAS).
>
> Most of the LAS won’t be active for the flight – not least because
>   there will be no humans on board the Orion.
>
> However, the jettison motor will be active, allowing for a separation
>   testing during the ascent phase. As such, this will be a nominal
>   detachment of the LAS when it is no longer required during the flight
>   into space, as opposed to an actual abort test.
>
> “The LAS will be the first actively controlled launch escape system
>   ever flown, and it incorporates a throttleable solid-rocket motor for
>   attitude control, a novel reverse-thrust abort motor, advanced solid
>   propellants, and lightweight composite materials in the abort motor
>   case and fairing,” noted LAS project manager for NASA, Kevin Rivers.
>
> The first ascent abort test of the LAS is scheduled for around 2019,
>   after the uncrewed Exploration Mission -1 (EM-1), but in plenty of
>   time ahead of the first crewed mission where it will be required,
>   namely Exploration Mission -2 (EM-2).

Other sources confirm this, for example the [Universe Today article on NASA Pressing Towards Fall 2014 Orion Test Flight – Service Module Complete](http://www.universetoday.com/107564/nasa-pressing-towards-fall-2014-orion-test-flight-service-module-complete/) from January 22, 2014.

More about the EFT-1 LAS can be read in the [NASASpaceflight.com article on ATK Launch Abort hardware arrives at KSC ahead of EFT-1](http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2013/02/atk-launch-abort-system-arrives-ksc-eft-1/) article on the same website.